# notepad++ search window over search results

Tags: notepad++

Not a biggy, but every time I search something, the searchwindow pop ups in the middle of the screen and covers the found results. 
Is there a way the search window is fixed on a position in the left top corner (or any place but the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The searchwindow pop ups in the middle of the screen and covers the found results.

If you click one of the "Find All ..." buttons you will get a separate (dockable) "Find result" window.